# Filter array by empty property

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting an array of objects as below in my Ajax response.

```
{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "An ice sculpture",
        "price": 12.50,
        "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 7.0,
            "width": 12.0,
            "height": 9.5
        },
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": -78.75,
            "longitude": 20.4
        }
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "A blue mouse",
        "price": 25.50,
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 3.1,
            "width": 1.0,
            "height": 1.0
        },
        "warehouseLocation": {
            "latitude": 54.4,
            "longitude": -32.7
        }
    }

    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "A blue mouse",
        "price": 25.50,
        "dimensions": {
            "length": 3.1,
            "width": 1.0,
            "height": 1.0
        },
        "warehouseLocation": ""
    }
```

I want to filter these objects by `warehouseLocation` which means I need only objects where `warehouseLocation` is not empty.

Comment: try using `.filter(...)`

Comment: Try To put @JsonInclude(Include.NON_EMPTY)  in your POJO class If you have your POJO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example to get started.

```js
var arr = [{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "An ice sculpture",
  "price": 12.50,
  "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
  "dimensions": {
    "length": 7.0,
    "width": 12.0,
    "height": 9.5
  },
  "warehouseLocation": {
    "latitude": -78.75,
    "longitude": 20.4
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "A blue mouse",
  "price": 25.50,
  "dimensions": {
    "length": 3.1,
    "width": 1.0,
    "height": 1.0
  },
  "warehouseLocation": {
    "latitude": 54.4,
    "longitude": -32.7
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "A blue mouse",
  "price": 25.50,
  "dimensions": {
    "length": 3.1,
    "width": 1.0,
    "height": 1.0
  },
  "warehouseLocation": ""
}]

var filteredArr = arr.filter(function(val) {
  if (val.warehouseLocation == "")
    return false;
  return true;
});

console.log(filteredArr);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) function:

```
var data = [{
    "id": 2,
    "name": "An ice sculpture",
    "price": 12.50,
    "tags": ["cold", "ice"],
    "dimensions": {
      "length": 7.0,
      "width": 12.0,
      "height": 9.5
    },
    "warehouseLocation": {
      "latitude": -78.75,
      "longitude": 20.4
    }
  }, {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A blue mouse",
    "price": 25.50,
    "dimensions": {
      "length": 3.1,
      "width": 1.0,
      "height": 1.0
    },
    "warehouseLocation": {
      "latitude": 54.4,
      "longitude": -32.7
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "A blue mouse",
    "price": 25.50,
    "dimensions": {
      "length": 3.1,
      "width": 1.0,
      "height": 1.0
    },
    "warehouseLocation": ""
  }
];

var warehouseData = data.filter(function(val) {
  return val.warehouseLocation != "";
});
```